# PowerMock class not found

Tags: java, junit, mockito, powermock

For some reason I fail to follow a pretty straight forward PowerMock example.

I included `powermock-mockito-1.5.1-full` in my classpath, and I try to test a public final method (following [this](http://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockFinal) example).

For some reason I am not able to make the import to the `PowerMock` class.

```
import org.junit.*;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;
import com.cleancode.lifesaver.camera.*;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(android.hardware.Camera.class)
public class CameraTests {

    private android.hardware.Camera _cameraMock;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        _cameraMock = PowerMockito.mock(android.hardware.Camera.class);
    }

    @Test 
    public void releaseCamera() {
        ICamera camera = new Camera(_cameraMock);

        // Compile error: PowerMock can't be resolved       
        PowerMock.replay(_cameraMock);
        // I also tried PowerMockito.replay(_cameraMock) but that also doesn't exist.

        camera.release();

        Mockito.verify(_cameraMock).release();
    }
}
```

As the comment explains, the `PowerMock` class can't be imported from the power mock jar.

It feels like a silly question, but I really can't find anything on the internet.

Where should I be able to find the static class `PowerMock`? I also used Java Decompile to search the powermock library, no hits on powermock / replay.

Comment: How have you included it in your classpath?

Comment: @vegemite4me, yes, only `PowerMock` class can't be found. `PowerMockRunner` and `PowerMockito` can be found and also compile, and run.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The example you are following `PowerMock.replay(_cameraMock);` is using EasyMock, while you seem to be wanting Mockito. Take a look at [this tutorial](http://www.jayway.com/2009/10/28/untestable-code-with-mockito-and-powermock/) for mockito & power mock

Comment: No need for facepalm, we all make silly mistakes. Cheers, i"m glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you not to create your mock in your `setUp()` (Before) method, because a mock is very complicated, for example you can tell it exactly how many time it should expect a method is called, if you declare a "general" mock for all your tests it's very difficult to control this behaviour.

maybe (without the code I can only guess) you want that your `android.hardware.Camera` is called inside your `Camera.release()` method, am I right? so I whould do like this:

The method you are trying to mock is not static, it's a normal final method. You can try to do this:

```
android.hardware.Camera mock = PowerMock.createMock(android.hardware.Camera.class);
PowerMock.expect(mock.release());
PowerMock.replay();

ICamera camera = new Camera(mock);
camera.release();
PowerMock.verify(mock);
```

if inside `camera.relase()` is not called exactly once the `android.hardware.Camera.release()` method the test fails.

Comment: I'm only creating the mock in my setup,  I'm not specifying behavior in it. But I was silly enough to use the wrong tutorial, as Grove pointed out. :-) thx though!

Comment: no prob ;) but I'm still on my advice not to use tearup unless that if extremely necessary.. working inside each test mean that you are separating all the code without problems of interaction. By the way, only an idea.

Comment: @Gianmarco: Could you please emphasise on your suggestion to not create the mock in setup? I would be very interested to understand your reasoning, because in my opinion it is easier and nicer. You get to reset the mock before each run (making sure one run does not influence another), and initialize the common behaviour. Then you can specify the custom behaviour for the current test method inside its body

Comment: I like much to separate the more I can each test so there can't be any problem in forgetting to reset the mock. It's only an opinion, but I like better to have all the behaviors under control in the test.

Comment: Well that was the nice part I was talking about. Recreating the mock in setup, automatically ensures that you don't forget to reset it :)